# Find words with exact number of characters

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

I have hundreds of lines like

```
1234 dfsdfdsfa INIUUININI112123424124 12321 JH7897IUHIH879KJ
```

and from each line, I want to get only words with exactly 9 characters (`dfsdfdsfa` in the example). How could I do it?

I tried many regexs/sed/grep/awk but without success.

Comment: Regex can do it for you, can you share any code you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a pure `bash` solution:

```
filename="test.txt"
declare -a record
while read -ra record
do
    for field in ${record[@]} 
    do
        if (( ${#field} == 9 ))
        then
            echo $field
        fi
    done
done < "$filename"
```

and here is an `awk` solution embedded in `bash`:

```
filename='test.txt'
awk -f - "$filename" << '_END_'
{
    for (i=1; i < NF; i++) {
        if (length($i) == 9) print $i
    }
}
_END_
```

Answer (score 3):

With grep:

```
$ grep -oE '\b.{9}\b' infile
dfsdfdsfa
```

`-o` returns only matches and not the complete lines; `-E` is because I'm lazy and don't want to escape the `{}` (as in `\{\}`).

The regex itself is "any 9 characters between word boundaries". This is not exactly foolproof and would also match `abcd efgh`, which can be avoided by indicating that we want non-blank characters only:

```
 grep -oE '\b[^[:blank:]]{9}\b' infile
```

Instead of using `\b...\b`, we could use the `-w` option to grep, which ensures the same.

Comment: grep has `-w` option to match words and `-x` option to match lines

Comment: @spasic Yes - but `grep -owE '.{9}'` would match `abcd efgh`, which I don't want. And I don't want `-x` either, as my match is just a word, not the whole line.

Comment: @spasic Ah, or did you just mean using `-w` instead of `\b...\b`? Fair enough, that would work.

Comment: yeah `-w` instead of `\b...\b` sorry about the confusion

Comment: @spasic I've added it to the answer, thanks for reminding me!

Answer (score 1):

`grep` with `-w` (`--word-regexp`) option:

```
grep -wo '.\{9\}' file.txt
```

Note that, word constituent characters are:

```
[[:alnum:]_]
```

**Example:**

```
% grep -wo '.\{9\}' <<<'1234 dfsdfdsfa INIUUININI112123424124 12321 JH7897IUHIH879KJ'
dfsdfdsfa
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cat foo.txt  | sed -e 's/[\t ]/\n/g' | awk '/^.{9}$/
```

should do the trick too.

Comment: Useless use of `cat`.

Comment: The OP didn't indicate how the lines were generated, `cat foo.txt` is a placeholder for whatever process is generating them. Hint was *foo* in there.